# Using findBy with same attribute but multiple values

Tags: hibernate, grails-orm, grails-domain-class

I have a Product domain:

```
Product {
   String name 
}
```

Now I need `issuedProductInstance` and `requestedProductInstance`. For that I used `findBy` as

```
def find(String issuedProduct,String requestedProduct){
    Product issuedProductInstance=Product.findByName(issuedProduct)
    Product requestedProductInstance=Product.findByName(requestedProduct)
}
```

In this way the method hits DB two times. Is there any way by which I can find both products by executing only one query.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about grails, but you just need the following query:

```
select p from Product p where p.name in (:names)
```

Of course, this query could return 0, 1 or 2 products, and you have to iterate through the list to know which is the one with "issuedProduct" as name, and which is the other one.

Comment: Yes, this will work. We can write it as Product.findAllByNameInList([issuedProduct,requestedProduct]).          But I want to show difference error message when issuedProductInstance or requestedProductInstance is null and this query will not return the null object.

Comment: If it returns an empty list, then both of them don't exist. If it returns a list of size 1, then one of them doesn't exist. If it returns a list of size 2, then both exist (assuming the name is unique, of course).